# Rectangle unwrapping to rhomboid

Tags: uv, edges, uv-image-editor

I'm doing a tutorial on unwrapping [(here if you have skillshare, part 5)](https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Blender-3D-UV-mapping-ultimate-guide/1290015422) and i'm at a step where i've marked my seams and i unwrap onto the teabox texture image. however, upon unwrapping the UV editor puts my seams offcenter and makes the edges angled, turning my rectangles into rhomboids when i rotate them.

ive tried unwrap settings at angled and conforming and it happens both ways. any thoughts here?[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: hi @moonboots here you go! (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5DDVK15Z/)

Comment: if you do a simple unwrap it will give a better result, the UV is tilted though (I've already noticed this bug I don't know how to fix it), just rotate the UV so that it's aligned with the axis